# Which pointer object (i.e., cursor) to use when resetting game.input.onDown

Tags: javascript, cursor, reset, phaser-framework

I'm having a problem where I need to reset the `game.input.onDown` event in the same way as [Phaser.Key.reset](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Key.html#reset). It seems like this is doable with the [Phaser.Pointer.reset](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Pointer.html#reset) method. Unfortunately, there seems to be a bunch of different potential pointer objects in the Phaser.Input class, and I'm not sure which one I need to use for `game.input.onDown`, which [says that it gets "dispatched each time a pointer is pressed down"](http://phaser.io/docs/2.3.0/Phaser.Input.html#onDown). I'm just not really sure which pointer I need to use. Can anyone shed some light on this?

I guess I effectively need to do something like this:

```
this.game.input.whicheverPointer.reset();
```

EDIT:

[Here is an example that mimics the the problem I'm having.](https://7ff594ca37c60276adb7b364ae05bfc5063d334b.googledrive.com/host/0B-ZLnDJaPrIYflBiaWpDMHR0UUhnOS14cG1aSzdYT0VVbkpCdzV5akdndGNkT0JVY1JGZmc/)

Here is the source code for it:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, "game", {preload: preload, create: create, update: update});

var dude;
var block;
var spacebar;
var gameOverText;

var gameOverCounter = 0;
var gameOverBool    = false;

function preload () {
  game.load.image("block", "assets/block.png");
  game.load.image("dude", "assets/phaser-dude.png");
}

function create () {
  dude  = game.add.sprite(373, 760, "dude");
  block = game.add.sprite(0, 505, "block");

  game.physics.arcade.enable(dude);
  game.physics.arcade.enable(block);

  dude.body.collideWorldBounds  = true;
  dude.body.gravity.y           = 200;

  block.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
  block.body.immovable          = true;

  block.body.velocity.x         = 100;
  block.body.bounce.x           = 1;

  spacebar = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);

  var jumpOrTryAgain = function () {
    if (gameOverBool === false) {
      dude.body.velocity.y = -250;
      // If you open up your JS / error console, you'll see that
      // this message gets printed an extra time each reset,
      // when you click. The spacebar doesn't have this problem
      // because of the `spacebar.reset()` call below.
      console.log("down");
    } else {
      dude.destroy();
      block.destroy();
      gameOverText.destroy();
      // Here, I can reset the spacebar, but I'm not sure what to do
      // for the click / touch event, which keeps getting the jumpOrTryAgain
      // callback added onto it.
      spacebar.reset();

      gameOverBool    = false;
      gameOverCounter = 0;

      create();
    }
  };

  game.input.onDown.add(jumpOrTryAgain);
  spacebar.onDown.add(jumpOrTryAgain);
}

function update () {

  function gameOver () {
    if (gameOverCounter === 0) {
      gameOverBool = true;
      dude.body.velocity.y  = 0;
      dude.body.velocity.x  = 0;
      block.body.velocity.x = 0;
      gameOverText = game.add.text(300, 200, "Game Over!", {fontSize: "16px", fill: "white"});
      gameOverCounter += 1;
    }
  }

  game.physics.arcade.collide(dude, block, gameOver);
}
```

As you can read in my comments above, the problem is that the click / touch event keeps getting the `jumpOrTryAgain` callback added onto itself as `create` gets recursively called when you reset the game. I need a way to reset the click / touch event, similar to `spacebar.reset()` as seen above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was implement a simple counter keeping the spacebar and pointer from getting re-assigned, like so:

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.CANVAS, "game", {preload: preload, create: create, update: update});

var dude;
var block;
var spacebar;
var gameOverText;

var gameOverCounter = 0;
var gameOverBool    = false;

var downCounter = 0;

function preload () {
  game.load.image("block", "assets/block.png");
  game.load.image("dude", "assets/phaser-dude.png");
}

function create () {
  dude  = game.add.sprite(373, 760, "dude");
  block = game.add.sprite(0, 505, "block");

  game.physics.arcade.enable(dude);
  game.physics.arcade.enable(block);

  dude.body.collideWorldBounds  = true;
  dude.body.gravity.y           = 200;

  block.body.collideWorldBounds = true;
  block.body.immovable          = true;

  block.body.velocity.x         = 100;
  block.body.bounce.x           = 1;

  var jumpOrTryAgain = function () {
    if (gameOverBool === false) {
      dude.body.velocity.y = -250;

      console.log("down");
    } else {
      dude.destroy();
      block.destroy();
      gameOverText.destroy();

      gameOverBool    = false;
      gameOverCounter = 0;

      create();
    }
  };

  if (downCounter === 0) {
    spacebar = game.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Keyboard.SPACEBAR);
    game.input.onDown.add(jumpOrTryAgain);
    spacebar.onDown.add(jumpOrTryAgain);
    downCounter += 1;
  }
}

function update () {

  function gameOver () {
    if (gameOverCounter === 0) {
      gameOverBool = true;
      dude.body.velocity.y  = 0;
      dude.body.velocity.x  = 0;
      block.body.velocity.x = 0;
      gameOverText = game.add.text(300, 200, "Game Over!", {fontSize: "16px", fill: "white"});
      gameOverCounter += 1;
    }
  }

  game.physics.arcade.collide(dude, block, gameOver);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`game.input.onDown` gets triggered from both mouse and touch input. If you need to reset its callback after every call, you can just use `game.input.onDown.addOnce()` (instead of `game.input.onDown.add()`) so that the callback is removed automatically after the first run.

Comment: Only problem with this is the fact that I need to have my game be clickable / touchable more than once. I just need the callback and whatnot cleared after a certain point. Thanks, though, your answer seems to be on the right track for what I need.

Comment: Ah, sorry for my misunderstanding. I think you can use `game.input.onDown.removeAll()` then when you decide - this will remove all listeners from the onDown event. Alternatively you can use `game.input.remove(listener)` where `listener` is the name of the listener function, although I suspect (naturally) that this has no way of working with anonymous functions.

Comment: Well, again, you gave me a good idea on how to fix this. The `remove` and `removeAll` methods didn't quite work when I tried to use them on my project, but the `game.input.onDown.dispose()` method did work and I was able to get my problem fixed. Here is my updated source code for the example: https://gist.github.com/ylluminarious/0c14293e4b41cf41d4da#file-main-js-L44-L53.

Comment: If you'd like, you can post an answer with that solution and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Oh wait, I just realized that the counter I implemented makes the disposal and re-assignment of the callback entirely obsolete. <_<;

Comment: Here is the code that fixes the problem without the unnecessary disposal and re-assignment of the callback: https://gist.github.com/ylluminarious/0c14293e4b41cf41d4da#file-main-js-L51-L56